# jQuery-mobile >> loading a page with form submission

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This should be a simple task. I'd like to submit a form and have the results displayed inside the "#responsediv" div, but no matter what I try all it does is reload the whole page.

I'm new to jquery-mobile; could someone please help out?
Thanks in advance! :-)

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="content" id="content1" name="content1">
    <form id="form1" >
      <div id="text1" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="text1">Text1:</label>
        <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="text2" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="text2">Text2:</label>
        <input id="text2" name="text2" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
        <button name="submitbtn" type="submit" id="submitbtn" />submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="responsediv"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
    $('#form1').submit(function() {
        $.mobile.loadPage("response.php",{
           type: "post",
           data: $("#form1").serialize(),
           pageContainer: $("#responsediv")
          });
    });
  </script>
```

---

Still not working, but here's my latest try:

```
$('#form1').on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.mobile.loadPage("result.php",{
                    type: "post",
                    data: $("#form1").serialize(),
                    pageContainer: $("#responsediv")
                  });
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `preventDefault` within your `submit` handler.

Edit:
Calling both `perventDefault` and `stopPropogation` seems to work as you expect.

```
   $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $.mobile.loadPage("/echo/html",{
       type: "post",
       data: $("#form1").serialize(),
       pageContainer: $("#responsediv")
     });
 });
```

See this sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/rcZ6G/).

Note that JQueryMobile `loadPage` inserts the response received into the target specified by `pageContainer` wrapped in a `div` with `data-role=page`

--- Edit 2 ---
I think [this example from JQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/forms-sample-selfsubmit.php) is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but in this case, the action still does not seem to work.

Comment: I've updated the code, which i'm currently messing around with.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on()` to bind the submit event when using jquerymobile instead of using `.submit()` short hand. 
Check out the jquerymobile event docs.

```
$('#form1').on('submit',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.mobile.loadPage("response.php",{
                    type: "post",
                    data: $("#form1").serialize(),
                    pageContainer: $("#responsediv")
                  });       
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but "on('submit'...)" didn't solve the problem either.
While "submit()" is causing the page itself to reload, "on()" doesn't seem to do anything. :-(